# How to change column position based on condition in a select query where having with clasue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

in the below query i have succeeded to get my data in a table starting from Jan, but i want to get starting month based on given date. 
ex: if month(inputdate) is 11 then table columns should start from nov and end with sep

I have tried with if else and dynamic query and not succeeded because of with clause

Any help would be appreciated!

```
WITH taskspecdata AS (select left(datename(month,max(approvalinfo_enddate)),3)as approvedMonth,
year(max(approvalinfo_enddate)) as approvedYear, month(max(approvalInfo_endDate)) as sortMonth,
Document_Id as docid,DocVersion_Counter as versions,docversion_Id as verid
from [webcenter].[WcReports_DocApprovalQ] where
(ApprovalInfo_EndDate)>= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and (ApprovalInfo_EndDate)<= GETDATE()
group by [WcReports_DocApprovalQ].DocVersion_Id,Document_Id,DocVersion_Counter)
select versions,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Jan' then 1 else 0 end) Jan,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Feb' then 1 else 0 end) Feb,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Mar' then 1 else 0 end) Mar,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Apr' then 1 else 0 end) Apr,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'May' then 1 else 0 end) May,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Jun' then 1 else 0 end) Jun,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Jul' then 1 else 0 end) Jul,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Aug' then 1 else 0 end) Aug,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Sep' then 1 else 0 end) Sep,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Oct' then 1 else 0 end) Oct,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Nov' then 1 else 0 end) Nov,
sum(case when approvedMonth = 'Dec' then 1 else 0 end) Dec from taskspecdata group by versions

Result columns:

versions    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

but i want to start from input month`enter code here`
if given month is nov then

versions    Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct
```

Comment: Try building the table "on its side" so you can use the ORDER BY and WHERE functionality. After that just PIVOT it.

Comment: sorry, did not get what's mean by "on its side"

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,Month where id>input data union 
select id,Month where  id<input data
```